# How do I highlight specific part in a image in macos Preview application

Tags: image-editing, preview, macos-sonoma

using Mac Os Sonoma v 14.2.1 and try to edit an image in **Preview** application and found 2 3 issues, so asking together.

I have captured the screenshot and then try to edit but unable to highlight specific text, which icon does this thing?

[image: screenshot of a regex syntax]

here I want to highligh `gi` changing the background of it

also how to use the first option, I am able to change the shape but it doesnt stay on the page as soon as we focus out so.

also the text always comes into the center and sometimes its hard to notice and we keep clicking. is there any option so that we can make it appear on other place?